# Apache - Redirection - Paths

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with redirect. Right now I have one page on address like:

```
http://localhost/Stella/Wiki/index.php
```

Also in the same directory I have my `.htaccess` file, which should redirect all requests to the `index.php`.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Stella/Wiki/index.php
RewriteRule (.*)$ /Stella/Wiki/index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This redirection works really good, but I want to use it in relative way, like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule (.*)$ /index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Like without absolute path, because I am going to have many subfolders, and I don't want to have long rules like: `/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/index.php`.

Can you help me to solve this problem? I don't know what to do, or if is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Stella/Wiki/index.php
> RewriteRule (.*)$ /Stella/Wiki/index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
> ```

If the `.htaccess` is located at `/Stella/Wiki/.htaccess` then you can write these directives like:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

As you suggested, this now uses *relative* paths. Note that relative paths don't start with a slash. If you use a slash prefix then that will be root-relative (ie. relative to the document root of the site).

When you use a relative path in per-directory `.htaccess` files then the directory-prefix (the filesystem path of where the `.htaccess` file is located) is added back at the end. So, `index.php` is in the directory where the `.htaccess` file is located. You can override this with the `RewriteBase` directive.

However, this a little different to your directives. Instead of a *condition* that only processes the directive if we are not already requesting the target URL. We have an exception that prevents any further directives being processed if that URL is already being requested.

Note, however, that this directs *all* requests to `index.php` (as your original directive does). Including requests for existing files and directories - if that is a concern?